# Date conversion issue for time series using plot.ts()

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a dataframe with date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and share prices but I can't see the date in the x axis when plotting it using `plot.ts()`. I have tried a few alternatives mentioned below but they did not work.

[image]

I converted the date using

1. `data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")`
   OR
2. `data$Date<-ymd(data$Date)` using the lubridate package

and then did

```
bby <- ts(data=data$Share_price, frequency=2, start=c(data[1,"Date"]))
plot.ts(bby))
```

It was unsuccessful.

I also tried

```
bby <- ts(data=data$Share_price, frequency=2,
     start=as.Date("2017-10-05"), end=as.Date("2019-10-04"))`
```

and then `plot.ts(bby)`

but again it did not work. I always end up with the below graph:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the future please provide your data in a cut and pasteable form, not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

The ts setup is a bit clunky and its plots are not always the friendliest. You could set up your data as follows. Note that you need to specify the 'start' for the time series object below in a rather painful manner, and then (because it only accepts regular time intervals)  you lose the day gap in the original series:

```
z <- seq.Date(as.Date('2017-10-05'), by = 1, length.out = 8)
data <- data.frame(Date = z[-(3:4)],
                   Share_price = c(1708.84, 1718.40, 1724.14, 1762.39, 1766.21, 1813.07))
myts <- ts(data$Share_price,
           start = c(2017, as.numeric(format(data$Date[1], "%j"))),
           frequency = 365)
plot(myts)
```

[image: Plot of ts object]

The x-axis now has decimal offsets from the year 2017.

Perhaps the xts package is better here? It can handle irregular time indices.

```
library(xts)
myxts <- xts(data$Share_price, data$Date)
plot(myxts)
```

[image]

See the plot.xts() documentation for all sorts of bells and whistles to embellish your graph.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes plot.xts() is much easier!

Comment: If this meets your requirements, please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally ts class is used for monthly, quarterly or yearly but not daily data.

Assuming that `DF` has Date and numeric columns as per reproducible form shown in the Note at the end, convert to zoo class.  Then we can easily plot using classic graphics, ggplot2 or lattice graphics.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF)

plot(z, main = "classic")

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z) + 

library(lattice)
xyplot(z)
```

### Plotting all three together using cowplot

```
library(gridGraphics)
library(cowplot)

plot(z)
p1 <- recordPlot()

library(ggplot2)
p2 <- autoplot(z)

library(lattice)
p3 <- xyplot(z)

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, labels = c("classic", "ggplot2", "lattice"), nrow = 1)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17444L, 17445L, 17448L, 17449L, 
17450L, 17451L), class = "Date"), Share_price = c(1708.84, 1718.4, 
1724.14, 1762.39, 1766.21, 1813.07)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```